# Extracting Mean from Raster and Writing to Table in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-10.1, table, loop

I am simply trying to extract the mean of each raster within a geodatabase and write the value to a table. I have done this successfully with another set of rasters, but now I keep getting the following error: *Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 8)*. I am at a loss for what is causing this.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "G:/Research/Sand Dams/Datasets/Ukraine.gdb/"

rasters=arcpy.ListRasters("*", "All")

for inRaster in rasters:
    UkrMEANResult = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(inRaster, “MEAN”)
    UkrMean = UkrMEANResult.getOutput(0)
    arcpy.CalculateField_management("RasterList","UkraineMean",UkrMean)
```

Comment: Check the double quotes around `MEAN` - it looks to me like they are not the standard ones - and the highlighting shows it too.

Comment: Try removing the last forward slash from the string where you set the workspace environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding an answer here for completeness, even though it seems that the question was answered in the comments.

As @PolyGeo noted, the quotes you have surrounding MEAN in the following line:

```
UkrMEANResult = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(inRaster, “MEAN”)
```

are referred to as curly quotation marks (also known as "smart quotes" or typographer's quotes). Some word processors, such as Microsoft Word, will sometimes automatically create these instead of straight quotes. **[This Office support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-curly-quotes-to-straight-quotes-and-vice-versa-017963a0-bc5f-486b-9c9d-0ec511a8fb8f)** page explains how to turn off the feature.